# Assigning variable inside a ternary if operator in razor views

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm facing a problem in which I have a variable declared and want to evaluate this and more conditions in an if ternary operator, but when I assign a variable inside this ternary operator I always get the variable in the HTML markup, so for example this code:

```
@{
    var panelTab = "";

    @(model.SelectedTab == "Overview" ? panelTab = "active" : "");

}
```

Will result in the word "active" inside the HTML DOM elements. I know what you are thinking, probably saying like, "that happens because of the @ symbol", but if I remove that symbol it also doesn't compile the ternary operator, so I'm stuck, any help?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

While [@adiga's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46551320/1875256) is helpful and will solve the problem what the OP is facing, but i would like to expand a little on it.

When you write :

```
@{

}
```

you are telling the razor that here the c# code block starts, now whatever c# code you write inside it would be like writing code in the `.cs` file, you don't need to put `@` in side that block.

`@` in only needed when we don't have explicitly declared the c# code block and we want to add some razor code which is of course c# expression or statement in combination with html then we use it.

Hope it helps you understand the difference of both.

Answer (score 1):

You're not using ternary operators the right way. Change it to:

```
@{var panelTab = model.SelectedTab == "Overview" ? "active" : ""};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//use in view body
<li class="Tab @(Model.SelectedTab == "Overview"?"active:"")"><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
```